# jQuery: Inconsistent behavior of find between div and tbody

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selector

I am using the `find` selector in jQuery by Id. It is behaving differently in case of a `div` vs `tbody`. This is a bigger problem - for the sake of clarity here is the reduced version of my original issue

**HTML**

```
<div id='iamdiv'>HELLO</div>
<table>
  <tbody id='iamtbody'>
    <tr><td>HELLO TOO</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type='text' id='div'/>
<input type='text' id='tbody'/>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var allcontent = $($('body').html()); // I am deliberately doing this to input a HTML String.
  var $divcontent = allcontent.find('#iamdiv');
  $('#div').val($divcontent.html());
  var $tbodycontent = allcontent.find('#iamtbody');
  $('#tbody').val($tbodycontent.html());
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bragboy/Lt8nua10/1/

I want to display the raw html in the input text boxes, however only the `tbody` one is getting displayed and not the `div`. If I use a `filter` method instead of `find` - it [works](https://jsfiddle.net/bragboy/Lt8nua10/3/) for div but not the tbody.

My objective is to have one consistent way of fetching for both tbody and div.

Comment: `var allcontent` is wrong. It  should be just `var allcontent = $('body')`;

Comment: @exabyssus - I deliberately did this because I need to parse a HTML version of string. If I just do `$('body')` it works which I already know. I want to parse a string and still solve the problem.

Comment: you could create a fake element to achieve that... something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/jolmos/Lt8nua10/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

1. `find` looks for *descendant* elements, but `#iamdiv` is a top-level entry in your `allcontents` jQuery object.
2. <s>You're duplicating the elements in the</s>

   ```
   var allcontent = $($('body').html());
   ```

   line, which I'm fairly sure isn't what you want to do. *(You've said that's on purpose, to simulate parsing HTML from elsewhere.)*

You've said your goal is to use `find` in both use case (rather than using `filter` in one and `find` in the other). To do that, you need to have something else as the root of your `allcontent`.

You've also said that for some reason you can't change the

```
var allcontent = $($('body').html());
```

line, even just to

```
var allcontent = $("<body>").append($('body').html());
```

That's okay, you can still add a new root element by adding a line after it, like this:

```
allcontent = $("<body>").append(allcontent);
```

Live example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var allcontent = $($("body").html()); // You've said we can't change this
  // The added line:
  allcontent = $("<body>").append(allcontent);
  var $divcontent = allcontent.find('#iamdiv');
  $('#div').val($divcontent.html());
  var $tbodycontent = allcontent.find('#iamtbody');
  $('#tbody').val($tbodycontent.html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='iamdiv'>HELLO</div>
<table>
  <tbody id='iamtbody'>
    <tr><td>HELLO TOO</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type='text' id='div'/>
<input type='text' id='tbody'/>
```

Comment: The piece `var allcontent = $($('body').html());` is very intentional as I am using the same HTML as a source to indicate what i want to parse. I cannot append a body tag here (as in my original problem i am implementing an infinite scroll feature). Without touching that line, is there any other solution?

Comment: @bragboy: I fail to see why you can't change that line. But sure, just add this on the next line: `allcontent = $("<body>").append(allcontent)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `var allcontent = $('body');` instead of `var allcontent = $($('body').html());`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var allcontent = $('body');
  var $divcontent = allcontent.find('#iamdiv');
  $('#div').val($divcontent.html());
  var $tbodycontent = allcontent.find('#iamtbody');
  $('#tbody').val($tbodycontent.html());
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 100%; /* just to show the whole content */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='iamdiv' class='somthing1'>
  HELLO
</div>
<table>
  <tbody id='iamtbody' class='somthing2'>
    <tr>
      <td>HELLO TOO</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type='text' id='div' />
<br/>
<input type='text' id='tbody' />
```

---

**After update in question :**

You can use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to achieve this. Because the cose that you picked when using `$($(body).html())` has the div as on its node.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var allcontent = $($('body').html());
  var $divcontent = allcontent.closest('#iamdiv');
  $('#div').val($divcontent.html());
  var $tbodycontent = allcontent.find('#iamtbody');
  $('#tbody').val($tbodycontent.html());
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 100%; /* just to show the whole content */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='iamdiv' class='somthing1'>
  HELLO
</div>
<table>
  <tbody id='iamtbody' class='somthing2'>
    <tr>
      <td>HELLO TOO</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type='text' id='div' />
<br/>
<input type='text' id='tbody' />
```

Comment: I deliberately did $($('body').html()) to simulate the example for parsing a HTML string.

Comment: @bragboy: That would be useful information to have included in the question.

Comment: @bragboy: Fortunately for me, I'd allowed for the possibility that you really wanted that line in my answer. :-)

Comment: Check the updated answer, after the updated question!

Comment: @HimanshuTyagi The OP asked for one way to get both elements, not two different ways. I don't know why though..

Comment: @JacquesMarais - The reason I want one way is because I am extracting this feature to a library for Inifinite scrolling and dynamically appending HTML on the fly to the existing result.